# Hide Polymer element

Tags: css, polymer

i try to hide several polymer elements on a certain element condition. I'm aware that there are several possibilities. In my opinon the easiest way to do this is to introduce a new CSS class

```
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

and add it to the class list of the polymer elements

```
this.$.icon.classList.add('invisible');
this.$.text.classList.add('invisible');
this.$.button.classList.add('invisible');
```

But this has no effect on the elements. The elements are still visible. A look into the elment inspector shows, that the class was added:

```
class="style-scope parent-elem invisible"
```

Where parent-elem is the name of the parent element.

Can anyone explain me why the element will not be hidden?

Thank you

Best Regards,
Meisenmann

Comment: Hi, sometimes, depending on how your elements are implemented and interact with each others, it can be because the new class is hidden in the shadow dom, or light dom. I had a similar issue with some external lib and the use of `Polymer.dom.flush()` after adding the class solved it.

Answer (score 2):

you can easly manipulate on your elements with parent `property`. Try in your element `properties` add `property`

```
properties: {
 ...
 elementsVisible: {
  type: Boolean,
  value: true
 }
 ...
}
```

then in your `method` manipulate this `property` and in `html` component set

```
<element hidden="[[!elementsVisible]]" ></element>
```

ps. if this wont work you can add in `parent css`

```
[hidden] {
  display: none;
 }
```

sometimes polymer elements need special mixins to customize their css, but hidden usually works :)

Comment: thank you for your anser. I hide elements if the text length of some properties of the host elment < 0. So i have to create an additional flag for each text property. In the solution above, i can add the CSS class in an observer without the need of an extra property.

Comment: In your example code you have written adding class to three elements, if you need just one flag to hide all those tree elements I would recommend you using Polymer property flag - you can easly control it (better than classes)

Comment: unfortunately i need a different flag for each component. why has the hidden class  no effect on the element?

Comment: sorry for the delayed answer. the parent component is a simple span container with a flex layout